# Tensorflow Datasets: Randomly sample 64 records from 10 randomly chosen datasets from 500 total datasets

Tags: tensor, tensorflow2.0

using tensorflow 2.0 to parse tfrecord datasets --

I need to sample N records from M random datasets from J total tensorflow `tfrecord` datasets.

for instance -

```
N = 10, the number of samples from each M datasets
M = 64, the number of randomly chosen datasets
J = 1000, the total number of `.tfrecord` datasets on disk
```

With a batch size of N.

generating a batch of (N, M) batch of `tf.Tensors`. Each batch is a random sample of N utterances from M speakers, from a total number of J speakers.

I see that both https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/choose_from_datasets

and

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/sample_from_datasets
exists but dont see a way to combine them. A suboptimal workaround would be to create a python generator that provides the samples but am looking for how to do this with tfrecords and the datasets API